# Minimizing 2-variable function with underdetermined constraint

Tags: mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I'm trying to minimize the function `eps` wrt the real variables `a1` and `a2`, making sure that these, together with the other three variables `b1`,`b2` and `b3` nullify the quantity `coeffGradR`. I've tried two ways to call `Minimize`. The first one returns an answer pretty quickly, the second one instead doesn't seem to converge and I have to abort it. Is the first one the correct form? Or am I making some mistakes? I don't care about the values of `b1`,`b2` and `b3` as long as they are real. I just want to minimize `eps` and force `coeffGradR = 0`. Thanks. Below is the code (the two calls were done in two different files, here I report them together for ease):

```
Q0 = a1 (b1 + b3) + a2 (b1 + b2) + b2 + b3 + 8 (b1^2 + b2^2 + b3^2) + 4 (b1 b2 + b1 b3 + b2 b3);
Q1 = Q0 / 2 / (1 + a1^2 + a2^2) + (a1 + a2 + a1 a2) / 8 / (1 + a1^2 + a2^2);
coeffGradR = Q1 + 1 / 12;
eps[x_, y_] := 1 / 24 / (1 + (x + y + x y) / (1 + x^2 + y^2));
Minimize[{eps[a1, a2], coeffGradR == 0}, {a1, a2, b1, b2, b3}] (* First version: this returns {1/12, {a1 -> -2, a2 -> 1, b1 -> 1/12, b2 -> -(1/6), b3 -> 1/12}} quite quickly *)
Minimize[{eps[a1, a2], coeffGradR == 0}, {a1, a2}, Reals] (* Second version: doesn't converge and requires abortion *)
```

My doubt is that since I'm minimizing just wrt `a1` and `a2`, so I don't think I should put `b1`,`b2` and `b3` in the variables placeholder between curly brackets.

Comment: I think this is an ill posed problem, as the minimum will depend on the values of b1,b2,b3.

Comment: @DanielHuber How so? Couldn't I pick e.g. b1 such that coeffGradR = 0 and then minimize eps wrt a1 and a2, and tweak b2,b3 such that b1 is real? (Since coeffGradR is quadratic in b1, we make sure the discriminant is >=0 to avoid complex solutions). Anyway do you think at least the call of Minimize is correctly written? I'm not sure if I'm achieving what I want with those calls